# Remove 1.5” spa pipe fitting from PVC pipe WITHOUT damaging pipe

Tags: pipe, pvc, removal, fitting

Have a 1.5” compression collar for a spa circulation pump.  Whoever installed it crushed the shoulder behind the “O” ring.  Need to remove it without having to buy a “pipe parana” for $140.  Have to remove the fitting WITHOUT damaging the pipe...no room for error, or re-doing other fittings.  Help?[image]

Answer (score 1):

heat it with a blow torch or hot air gun until it softens then slit it with a knife and peel it off